# Linq: get a custom class joining to tables

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, entity-framework

I'm developing a WCF RESTful service with C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and Entity Framework Code First.

I have this class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Group
{
    [DataMember]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Country { get; set; }

    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**And this class**:

```
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

I want to retrieve a `group` using its `GroupId` and all its members (as an array of `UserId`).

Now, I have this sentence:

```
var groups = from g in context.Groups
where g.GroupId == groupId
select g;
```

But I don't know how can I get member's `UserId`.

I want to get a custom class like this one:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomGroup
{
    [DataMember]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Country { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<int> UsersIds { get; set; }
}
```

**How can I do that?**

Comment: it's not clear what you want, the `Group` already has `Users` collection, isn't that what you want? Or you want to expose the `UserId` directly? If so you may have to use `anonymous type` or another custom class.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, I want to expose the UserId directly.

Comment: @KingKing I've updated my question with better details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = context.Groups.Where(g=>g.GroupId == groupId)
                    .Select(e=> new CustomGroup(e));
//With your CustomGroup class should looks like this:

[DataContract]
public class CustomGroup  //You should consider some inheritance relationship here
   public CustomGroup(Group g){
      GroupId = g.GroupId;
      Name = g.Name;
      Description = g.Description;
      City = g.City;
      Country = g.Country;
      UsersIds = g.Users.Select(u=>u.UserId).ToList();
   }
   //....  
   [DataMember]
   public ICollection<int> UsersIds { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you'd do this:

```
var members = context.Groups.Where(group => group.GroupId == groupId).SelectMany(g => g.Users.Select(usr => usr.UserId));
```

Comment: @VansFannel after reading your updated question, this is still my response :)